# Using findViewById more effeciently

Tags: java, android

I am currently using the following code and wondering if there is a more effecient way of doing this via a function?

```
showDisplay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.display1);
if (isA)
{ 
{ showDisplay.setVisibility(0);}
else
{ showDisplay.setVisibility(8); }


showDisplay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.display2);
if (isB)
{ showDisplay.setVisibility(0);}
else
{ showDisplay.setVisibility(8); }

showDisplay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.display3);
if (isC)
{ showDisplay.setVisibility(0);}
else
{ showDisplay.setVisibility(8); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this

```
// Do this in your onCreate method and store the references as class member variables
showDisplay1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.display1);
showDisplay2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.display2);
showDisplay3 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.display3);

// Do this somehwere in your code
showDisplay1.setVisibility(isA?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
showDisplay2.setVisibility(isB?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
showDisplay3.setVisibility(isC?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
```

For **efficiency** it's important to store the references as member variables, as calling findViewById is a quite expensive action (compared to accessing a member variable), because you'll only ever need to call it once when the application is created (this also accounts for orientation changes, as the Activity gets destroyed and is recreated again).

And it's quite clean and tidy. Inline if-expressions are very usefull for this kind of functions, where you only have either that or this.

```
myFunction((expression)?if_value:else_value);
```

is short of

```
int value = 0;
if(expression) {
    value = if_value;
} else {
    value = else_value;
}
myFunction(value);
```

you can basically ignore the `( )` if the variable is already a boolean, if not you have to put the brackets. So this will work fine too

```
myFunction((someVariable>3)?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
```

**Edit2:**

```
int value = 0;
if(somveVariable > 3) {
    value = View.VISIBLE;
} else {
    value = View.GONE;
}
myFunction(value);
```

So instead of making a variable to hold a value you want to pass to a function, you can do it all inline.

**Edit:**
Oh and btw: Please, never use `0` or `8` for `View.setVisibility(...)` method. This is a very bad practice and will break your application if the values ever change in future. `View.VISIBLE` is already a `public static final int`, which means the compiler will replace all occurrences of `View.VISIBLE` with a `0`. In byte code it's same as using `0`, no performance impact, but if the value is ever to be changed, all the change will automatically occur on compile time with the new SDK and no manual modification is needed, while with your attempt you would have to replace every single `0` and `8` with the new values!

Comment: Cool, that worked well. What if I wanted to call another function within the if statement as well? E.g. ig isA, hide and also run another function.

Comment: You can do this as well, everything that works in normal `if`'s, work there as well

Comment: Hmmmm, I must not be getting the syntax right. I was trying showDisplay1.setVisibility(isA?View.VISIBLE,functionA();:View.GONE);

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of the functionA(), you don't need it there

Comment: No such luck, I get the following error: Cannot invoke functionA() on the primitive type int

Comment: Well after a close look, you're having `View.VISIBLE,functionA();` in the first part, but this kind of if-expressions more more meant to pass one value or another. Basically you either put a literal there, a variable or a return value of a function. You you can have either `View.VISIBLE` or `functionA()` inside the `if_true_do_this` part but not both

Comment: Guess what you really wanted was `(functionA())?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE`. Depends on what functionA does. if it returns a true/false value, its good this way. Well, I'll edit my answer, maybe its more clear then on the syntax part

Answer (score 2):

I usually have a bunch of helpers for setting common properties like visibility, text, etc. It makes the code look prettier.

```
setChildVisibility(R.id.display1, isA);
setChildVisibility(R.id.display2, isB);
setChildVisibility(R.id.display3, isC);
```

With the helper being :

```
protected void setChildVisibility(int id, boolean visible) {
    View view = findViewById(id);
    if (view != null) {
        view.setVisibility(visible?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
public void showDisplay(int displayId, boolean show) {
    if (show) {
      ((LinearLayout)findViewById(displayId)).setVisibility(0);
    }
    else {
      ((LinearLayout)findViewById(displayId)).setVisibility(8);
    }
}

showDisplay(R.id.display1, isA);
showDisplay(R.id.display2, isB);
showDisplay(R.id.display3, isC);
```

The code becomes more readable, not more efficient.